# dd loop input File to output device?

Tags: dd

Using the `/dev/zero` to erase an HDD is very slow, so I'm going to use a prepared file of 1GB with random or zeros.

But how can I loop this File with `dd`?

```
dd if=loopfile of /dev/sdx
```

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/zero` is not slow at all, maybe all you need is `dd bs=1M`. Should do several gigabytes per second, so the HDD/SSD is the bottleneck.

```
# dd bs=1M status=progress if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
234309550080 bytes (234 GB, 218 GiB) copied, 11 s, 21.3 GB/s
```

Or just go with `shred`.

```
# shred -v -n 1 /dev/eraseme
```

That should go with (pseudo)random data at full HDD speed. If it must be zero then `-n 0 -z` but with `shred` it won't be any faster than random data.

Comment: Now I use the shred command. dd with zeros need 240h, shred only 24h.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here for you is that the default blocksize for `dd` is 512 bytes, so that's two system calls and two requests for IO per KB. You've got two million of those per GB; no wonder it's slow.

- Don't use `dd`. Use `cat` (it's far faster in many situations and rarely, if ever, slower):

  ```
  cat /dev/zero >/dev/sdX
  ```
- If you really must use `dd`, increase the blocksize to something rational:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero bs=32M of=/dev/sdX
  ```
- If you're trying to erase the disk with pseudo-random data, consider [DBAN](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/) with a single pass. (Don't bother with multi-pass; either one pass is sufficient or you need a [hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer).)